# How i print a stack using printStream argument in java?

Tags: java, interface, stack, java-io, printstream

This is a method from an interface which i have to implement in another class and i don't know how to create it. I have to print the stack using linkedList with printStream argument. Inside the class Node(for linkedList) i have a method getObject().

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public interface StringStack {


    public boolean isEmpty();

    public void push(String item);

    public String pop() throws NoSuchElementException;

    public String peek() throws NoSuchElementException;

    /**
     * print the contents of the stack, starting from the item
         * on the top,
     * to the stream given as argument. For example, 
     * to print to the standard output you need to pass System.out as
     * an argument. E.g., 
     * printStack(System.out); 
     */
    public void printStack(PrintStream stream);

    public int size();

}




public class StringStackImpl implements StringStack {
    private Node head;
....
    public void printStack(PrintStream stream) {???}

}
```

Comment: How do you want to print the stack, 1 object per line or all objects on single line?

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are facing? Start by printing data from head node, then go to next node and print it. Repeat until there will be no more nodes left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how is the structure of your stack but this should do:

```
  Node node = head; // top of the stack

  while(node != null){
     stream.println(node.value);
     stream.flush();
     node = node.next;
  }
```

Comment: i have to print until the given stream so its gonna be while(head.getObject() != stream) ??

Comment: You are printing every object from your stack to a OutputStream, which is either a file or the console standart output. I think you need to get more familiar with streams and basic I/O.